# how to round a number in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I used String.format() to round to the third decimal place. However this didn't work and I solved it using DecimalFormat. Is there anything I implemented wrong?

```
val value = 36.295f
Timber.e("format: ${"%.2f".format(value)}")
```

expect: 36.30 but result: 36.29

Comment: You are using the right syntax, just remove the f, you will get the expected result. Or you have to use `DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `f`

```
val value = 36.295
Timber.e("format: ${"%.2f".format(value)}")
```

Comment: Not correct. The only probleam is the `f`,

Answer (score 4):

Due to floating-point inaccuracies, 36.295f is not exactly 36.295 but rather something like 36.294998. This is the explanation for the output you received.

I believe your best option is to increase the precision in the input to start with. Use double-precision floating point i.e. lose the `f` for single-precision floating point.

`DecimalFormat` by itself cannot add precision to imprecise numbers. For example, The `RoundingMode.CEILING` approach offered in another answer would e.g. round 36.294 to 36.3 which might not be what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Use this example to show you how to round:

```
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.text.DecimalFormat

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val value = 36.295f
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING

    println(df.format(value))
}
```

**Output:**
36.30

So for your code you can use:
`df.format(value)` as your value

Check this link for more details: [Link](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/round-number-decimal).