# how do i restric a float value to only one placess after decimal in kotlin android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a number with some number decimal places,
How can i round this float number with one number decimal places

for example
`1.366565646` convert to `1.3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round Double to 1 decimal place kotlin: from 0.044999 to 0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011924/round-double-to-1-decimal-place-kotlin-from-0-044999-to-0-1)

Comment: Floats don't _have_ decimal places, they only have binary places, and the two aren't exactly interchangeable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to round a number in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66195651/how-to-round-a-number-in-kotlin)

Comment: yes this answer is correct but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49012345/8680451) is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case I think you need to trim the number not round it,
You can use this:

```
 double d = 1.366565646;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
 double p = Double.parseDouble(df.format(d));
```